# A Batch class for trigger? Or there is another solution?

Tags: trigger, batch, before-trigger, bulkification

I have a trigger for many records. In my unit test there is no problems with 1500 records. But I'm getting the 'Apex CPU time limit exceeded' error with 1800 and more records. Is Batch the only solution to this problem? And if yes, how to write a Batch class for the trigger?

Trigger:

```
trigger myTrigger on Tool__c (before insert, before update) {
    TriggerHelper trHelper = new TriggerHelper();

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        trHelper.toolFieldSetup(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Trigger Helper:

```
public class TriggerHelper {
    public void toolFieldSetup(List<Tool__c> newTools){
        Set<Id> setOppIds = new Set<Id>();
        Opportunity opportunityForTool = new Opportunity();

        for(Tool__c tool : newTools){
            if(tool.Opportunity__c != null && tool.Special_Tool_date__c >= Date.TODAY()-30){
                setOppIds.add(tool.Opportunity__c);
            }
        }
        Map<Id,Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Level__c FROM Opportunity
                            WHERE Id IN : setOppIds]);

        for(Tool__c newTool : newTools){
            if(newTool.ToolField__c != null) continue;
            if(oppMap.get(newTool.Opportunity__c) != null) opportunityForTool = oppMap.get(newTool.Opportunity__c); 
            if(opportunityForTool == null) continue;

            if(opportunityForTool.Level__c < 50) newTool.ToolField__c = 60;
            else newTool.ToolField__c = 100; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan, triggers run 200 records at a time in each "context", so they are already batched in a way.  Are there any Process Builders, Workflow Rules or Flows attached to this object? If so, start there.

Comment: Alternatively, the trigger you wrote is a relatively simple PB, perhaps that's a better solution here

Comment: No. The point is that we can use a data loader or apex script with updating 3000+ records per once. And PB just can't handle so much.

Comment: That's both true and false (the right answer is "Depends"). What makes you think PB can't handle this? Also, are there PBs, Flows and WFRs already in this object?

Comment: Yes, there are some processes, but not for this object. Because PB can work only with 200 records per once. I need much more. Up to 5000. Or at least 3000.

Comment: Salesforce will break up everything internally in batches of 200. Even triggers run in batches of 200. Try this by doing a "System.Debug" inside of that trigger and you'll see.

The problem is the org itself, not the technology you're using. What I mean is, look at the org holistically and try to slim down overall. and it's possible that 3k is just too much for your org, period.

Comment: We need to make a key distinction here between a trigger batch and a transaction. Data Loader is not going to upload 3000 records in a transaction unless you specifically ask it to.

Comment: @DavidReed Data loader isn't going to load 3000 in one batch, ever, as the API limit per call is 200. The only time you can even exceed 200 records per API call is Apex. TMYK.

Comment: I still don't get it. I CAN run this logic for 1500 records. But can't for 1800+ because of CPU limits. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a problem only in your unit test, then it's not a problem. The only you can even get as high as 1800 records is during Apex code execution, as the maximum request size for all other APIs is 200 records per transaction. If you don't have any code that handles this many records in a single transaction, you'll be fine.

FYI, if you did need more limits, Queueable and future are the only two types you should call from a trigger. Batchable classes are limited to a queue of up to 105 deep (5 active plus 100 pending), while Queueable and future support many thousands of items in the asynchronous queue. In unit tests, though, you can only execute a limited number of batches, future, queueable, etc, because they're meant to be logic tests, not stress tests.

Comment: So I just have to add `@future` to my helper methods?

Comment: @DanDan You'll need to either serialize the data or pass in just the ID values, as only primitives are supported, not complex objects (lists are primitives). It's a little more work than just adding the annotation, but shouldn't be too hard.